# Oracle PDB Container Database using Docker/YML file

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, pdb

Is it possible to create an Oracle PDB Container Database using a YML file similar to Docker file format.

IF Oracle calls PDB/CDB as Pluggable Container Database, shouldn't the container file format be similar to Docker?

Thanks, Rajesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion of container is different between Oracle Multi-tenant DB and Docker.

In Oracle Multi-tenant DB; container refers to [pluggable/root database](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdbovrvw.htm#CNCPT89236).

Where as [Docker container](https://www.docker.com/what-docker):

> Docker containers wrap a piece of software in a complete filesystem
>   that contains everything needed to run: code, runtime, system tools,
>   system libraries – anything that can be installed on a server.

Like `.yml/.yaml` is used for Docker compose file, `.xml` is used to [plug/unplug a PDB](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/pdb/pdb_unplug_plug/pdb_unplug_plug.html).

Comment: Well it is not what I expected from a "container" database. I believe oracle is just riding on the container marketing. I am very familiar with docker. Thanks for the explanation. The xml file to unplug/plug a PDB shows that you are tied to Sqlplus and Oracle proprietary technology to create PDB and mount/plug it in a cdb.